Can a collimated laser have curved wavefronts?
I know that a plane wave's collimation is affected by the curvature of its wavefronts. But since laser beam is composed of many plane waves, does it still apply ? Although there is always some divergence, due to diffraction, does wavefront curvature have a huge difference in beam's collimation?
Thanks

Yes, most lasers have curved wave fronts. Many lasers are Gaussian.
